# “Memory Trace Upload was successful” message randomly appeared on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

While in the Facebook app, a grey box with light grey text appeared randomly at the top of the screen, saying “Memory Trace Upload was successful”. I don’t have a jail broken iPhone and did not do anything to ‘ask’ for a memory trace to be uploaded.

[image]

If it’s a standard debugging thing, how do I turn off this level of access for app developers and/or Apple?

Answer (score 1):

Apple and iOS do not have that as a standard dialog or feature - Apple crash reports and memory traces are logged and controlled much differently than how the Facebook App is designed.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202100
- https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/414/
- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Apart from the link above on whether you have Apple share analytics you report back to the developer, you can inspect your iOS device in settings to see what the Facebook app is logging to Apple and possibly through them to Facebook when you opt in to Apple’s analytics sharing process.

- https://support.omnigroup.com/ios-crash-log/

  1. Open Settings.app.
  2. Tap Privacy, then scroll down and tap Analytics.
  3. Tap Analytics Data.
  4. Locate the log for the app that crashed. The filename will use this format: **<AppName>_<DateTime>_<DeviceName>**
  5. Tap the crash log to open it.

Assuming you have discovered this message is in-app diagnostics and not iOS / Apple diagnostics and opting out from Apple collection, **uninstall the Facebook app as a quick fix** to remove the memory upload message that it is sharing with users when it it letting you know a trace has left your device.

You would of course need to use Safari to access your feed until the app developer either explains to you why they are letting you know a trace is uploaded or opt out of analytic / memory trace collection within the Facebook app.